# Output of complete script to variable

Tags: bash, output-redirect

I have rather complex bash script which is normally run manually and thus needs live output on the console (stdout and stderr).
However, since the outcome and output of this script is rather important I'd like to save its output at the end into a database.

I have already a `trap` function for this and the database query as such is also not a problem. The problem is: How do I get the output of the entire script till that point into a variable?

The live console output should be preserved. The output after the database query (if any) does not matter.

Is this possible at all? Might it be necessary to wrap the script into another script (file)?

Comment: Use `tee`  to add output to a file and read from file

Comment: Show the script you have, with a minimal reproducible example and an _exact_ output you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing similar task like this

```
exec 5>&1
message=$(check|tee /dev/fd/5)
mutt -s "$subjct" "$mailto" <<< "$message"
```

Add your script instead of `check` function and change mailing to db query.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I think that goes in the right direction. I have put a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792514/wrong-exit-code-for-variable-function-call-assignment-in-subshell