# Wrong exit code for variable function call assignment in subshell

Tags: bash, exit-code, subshell

I have a script which quite often fails. It is crucial that the correct exit code is passed on.

This code works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function my_function {
    echo "Important output"
    exit 1
}

function cleanup {
  MY_EXIT_CODE=$?
  echo "MY_EXIT_CODE: ${MY_EXIT_CODE}"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

my_function
```

`MY_EXIT_CODE` is `1` as expected and running `echo $?` after the script gives me `1` as well (as expected)

However, I need to get the complete output of `my_function` both to a variable and the console output. In order to do so, as advised in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63788764/2710714) (which seems itself based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292136/2710714)) I changed my code into

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function my_function {
    echo "Important output"
    exit 1
}

function cleanup {
  MY_EXIT_CODE=$?
  echo "MY_EXIT_CODE: ${MY_EXIT_CODE}"
}

trap cleanup EXIT

exec 5>&1
FF=$(my_function|tee /dev/fd/5)
```

And now the exit code is wrong. Is it `0` while it should be `1`. I know this is somewhat connected to subshell handling but I couldn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Take a look at array PIPESTATUS: `declare -p PIPESTATUS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And now the exit code is wrong. Is it 0 while it should be 1

No, your assumption is wrong. Assuming `tee` succeeded, the exit code should be 0. From the [posix shell manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_02):

> If the reserved word ! does not precede the pipeline, the exit status shall be the exit status of the last command specified in the pipeline.

The "last command" in a pipeline is the rightmost command. Because in your case `tee` exits with 0, the exit status of `FF=$(.... | tee)` is zero.

> how to solve it.

That depends on the behavior you want to achieve. Usually, in bash you may just `set -o pipefail` to always catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that simply stating

```
set -o pipefail
```

at the beginning of the script file did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's subshell and pipe, try like this

```
FF=$(my_function|tee /dev/fd/5; exit $PIPESTATUS)
```